# Extract substrings from file

Tags: shell, sed

I have this file:

```
export CROSS_COMPILER=gcc-arm
export SDK=1
#
#   blabla bla
#
if [ `expr $SYSTEM : '.*x86.*'` -ne 0 ]
then
   export X86
fi
```

I want to extract variables of this file using sed. As a result I want to display:

```
CROSS_COMPILER
SDK
X86
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*export \([^=]*\).*/\1/p' infile
CROSS_COMPILER
SDK
X86
```

- `-n` prevents printing.
- The substitution captures on lines matching `export` everything between `export` and the equal sign (or the end of the line if there is none), then replaces the whole line with the capture group.
- The `p` flag prints the line.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer,

```
grep -Po 'export \K[^=]+' file
```